# In the SMS protocol is there such a thing as a "reply"

Tags: sms

Is there a mechanism in the SMS protocol to associate a response with the message it is responding to?  Does a reply carry with it any piece of data that would uniquely identify the message it is responding to?

Comment: What SMS protocol are you talking about ? SS7 map, SMPP, ... ?

Comment: I plead ignorance. Whatever protocol(s) would be used by SMS gateways like Twilio or Nexmo.

Comment: Well, every SMSC architecture has a message-id associated with the SMS being sent toward to, and also they provide protocols within the network operator to deal with it (like SMPP,UCP,CIMD etc..).
I assume Twilio or Nexmo are operator 3rd party customer attached to them using one of those protocols, so I am pretty sure they offer mechanism to return that message id (or their own-generated) to clients when they submit sms to be sent.